# Как достать значение из флажков?

Tags: php, mysql

Проблема в том, что я не могу достать значение из флажков `checkbox`.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int, id_school, id FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_parent' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_school IN ('$id_school', '$id_school1')");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo'</br>';
echo '<input class="i_parent" type="checkbox" name="sold[]" value='.$row[5].' >';
echo '<p class="s_parent">';
echo $row[0].' '.$row[1].' '.$row[2]. '-' . $row[3];
echo'</p>';
}
```

На другой странице мне надо достать значение. 
И потом их занести в БД.
Пробывал это

```
       print_r( $_POST['name'] );
```

но оно читает только одно значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя у input атрибут name = sold[], а это значит что для того чтоб достать нужно смотреть $_POST['sold']. До этого где то выше должна быть открыта форма с указанием метода post

Comment: Совет на будущее - когда смотришь **POST** всегда делай

     print_r($_POST);   // и таких проблем никогдa  не будет

PS: совет для ТСа :)

Comment: у мя есть форма, я ее просто не написал

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к N-ому элементу ( или с именем N) можно получить так

```
$_POST['sold'][N] = ($_POST['sold']['N'])
```

Если же потребуется получить все чекбоксы переданные формой, бегаем циклом

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST['sold']);$i++)
{
echo $_POST["sold"][$i];
}
```